# setup.exe does not work when copied from CD to hard drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, setup, installer

I have a CD where I burnt all the files required to install a program and when I run setup.exe it installs as expected. Today, I have noticed that if I copy the contents of the CD to my computer and I try to run setup.exe the installation fails. In particular, it is unable to load the files from the folders that were copied together with the setup.exe files. It gives the error "Impossible to find conf\10" and it prompts me to provide a valid installation path but all paths are rejected with error invalid path. What's causing this?

Comment: At a guess, it may be looking for the files as part of a path to a CD/DVD drive. One possible solution may be to try creating either an ISO image of the orginal disk directly or turning the files you copied into an ISO image and use some virtual CD drive software to mount that image.